Ошибка при обновлении chromadb отказано в доступе к файлу

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5]
Отказано в доступе:
'C:\Users\MAGICBOOK\PycharmProjects\forteachers\venv\Lib\site-packages\hnswlib.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'
Check the permissions.

это сама ошибка.Не знаю,что делать
Я сначала установил более старую версию библиотеки, но она конфликтует с новой версией langchain, выдает ошибку:

AttributeError: 'Collection' object has no attribute 'upsert'

